# How to Replace special characters in hive columns?

Tags: hive, regexp-replace

I have a requirement in hive, where need to replace the non-alphanumeric characters with _.
The data in column is "Pranav_Wagde_job_1163_W.Pranav Ltr-Resume 04.07.2016.pdf"

```
SELECT FILENAME, REGEXP_REPLACE(FILENAME,"[^0-9a-zA-Z._]", "_"), FROM HIVEDB.FILEDATA WHERE FILENAME='Pranav Wagde_job_1163_W.Pranav Ltr-Resume 04.07.2016.pdf';
```

The output is

```
Pranav_Wagde_job_1163_W.Pranav Ltr-Resume 04.07.2016.pdf
```

I am unable to replace the dots in the file name.
How to replace all the dots in data except the extension of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a positive lookahead is supported, you could add an alternation `|` matching all dots except one that has 1+ word chars at the right followed by the end of the string.

```
(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z._]|\.(?!\w+$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pBuwLD/1)

Comment: Getting the output as ___________________________________________________________.

Comment: @Pranav Try it double escaping the dot `\\.` or `(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z._]|[.](?!\w+$))` https://regex101.com/r/Sd68ae/1

Comment: Thanks The fourth bird.   

Your RegExp is working the tool provided by you in the hyperlink, but unfortunately it is not working in hive.
I am getting an output as 
```
Pranav_Wagde_job_1163_W_Pranav_Ltr_Resume_04_07_2016_pdf
```

Comment: Try double eacaping the other backslash as well like `\\w+`

Comment: @Pranav The whole pattern would be `(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z._]|\\.(?!\\w+$))`